# The referenced component 'SHDocVw' could not be found

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, shdocvw

Compiling a solution on a new "build" server is throwing

> The referenced component 'SHDocVw' could not be found.

Solution builds fine on other build servers and on developers machines. I could swear it built fine two days ago.

One noticeable difference for this server is that is a Windows 2008 R2. Other build servers are Windows 2012 and developer machines range form Windows 8.1 to 10.

I tried removing the reference and add it again (COM reference Microsoft Internet Controls) with no luck.

More from the error message:

> Could not resolve COM reference "eab22ac0-30c1-11cf-a7eb-0000c05bae0b" version 1.1. Strong name key container not found.

Comment: I ran "sfc /scannow" as suggested on some articles and Windows did not find any integrity violations

Comment: Also tried regsvr32.exe "C:\Windows\System32\shdocvw.dll". EE down the lines of "was loaded but the entry-point dllregisterserver was not found"

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer recall the issue. Should I delete this question? Close it somehow?

Comment: That's alright. I've found that forcing `x86` build platform solved the issue for me. I'll post an answer here in-case anyone else faces a similar issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many years this happened to me again today. This time I was able to fix it.

It's a permission issue on the C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys folder.

Just give the user executing the action full access to this folder.

Answer (score 1):

After verifying that the version of `SHDocVw` was an `x86` assembly, I was able to solve this issue by explicitly including `<PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>` in my `csproj` `PropertyGroup` for the configuration and platform that I wanted to Strong Name, Delay Sign.